# XAMPP phpinfo does not detect Xdebug configuration in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I downloaded the .dll file for the right PHP version that I use (php **7.2**) with XAMPP v3.2.3; I placed the file in `C:\xampp\php\ext` and set this in the ini file and restarted Apache :

```
output_buffering=Off
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
zend.assertions=1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

But still, `phpinfo()` does not show any Xdebug configuration...

What could be wrong ? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: XAMPP means Apache ... therefore I believe you need a TS version of Xdebug (and not NTS like you are trying to use right now). The file should be called `php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll` as I understand (for x64 bit version of PHP). Try that.

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP means Apache ... therefore you need a TS (Thread Safe) version of Xdebug (and not NTS like you are trying to use right now).

The file should be called `php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll` as I understand (for x64 bit version of PHP): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll